What are approaches to identify the meaning of columns in a dataframe based on similarity to known column instances
In my domain we can perform upon to 12 tests on a substance, and record results for each of the tests at different pressures e.g. between 10 and 20 steps between 0 and 6000 psi. for each substance this results in a dataset like:
'''pressure={0,100, 300,...5000, 5500, 6000}
propA={0.1, 0.2, 0.3,...1.2, 1.4, 1.5}
propB={nan, nan, nan,...0.9, 0.8, 0.7}
propD={0.3, 0.5, 0.4,...nan, nan, nan}
etc.'''
each dataset will have pressure, but then an arbitrary set of the other properties. There is a standard set of column names we want to describe the data with after the fact, but the columns as captured in each dataset are not labelled well, if it all. There is no standardization in the columns names depending who recorded the data and when, there may or may not be similarity between the column names and the standards we wish to use. In addition the OCR process we use to capture the data from old reports may introduce spurious text.
We want to try to identify the correct column name for each column of data in a dataset by comparing the data values and patterns to a few hundred datasets where we have done the mapping to the correct column names. We're trying to characterize features of a column like monotonically increasing or decreasing, magnitude, zero-crossing, leading or trailing nans, etc. to at least identify possible columns, but haven't looked at the relationship between columns.
One more layer to this. There are several different testing procedures that can be used. Each procedure can evaluate a unique but overlapping subset of the 12 properties. We can start by identifying the procedure, manually or through other mechanisms, to reduce the set of possible columns, but we'd also like to go the other way and predict what procedure was used based on the columns that are found in the dataset.
so a few questions:

given we can identify some features about column data, what is the best way to use them to train a model?
are there standard ways to characterize column (series) data like this?
are there well-established approaches for mapping column data to known standard names?
how can we classify what procedure (object) the dataset represents based on values in the columns.

Note, I'm looking for guidance on how to approach this and can do my own research once pointed in the right direction.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
